# How can i make few children dynamic routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I need few dynamic route in Vue router like

/payouts/:person
/payouts/:pay_id

I tried make some children routes but its not working, its work like this only with id but it not what i want

```
  {
     path: 'payouts',
     name: 'Payouts',
     meta: {
       title: 'Payouts'
     },
     component: () => import('@/pages/Payouts'),

   },
   {
     path: 'payouts/:pay_id',
     name: 'Pay_id',
     meta: {
       title: 'Pay'
     },
     component: () => import('@/pages/Pay_id'),
   },
```

Comment: Are you sending Params(pay_id) when not sending any id ?

Comment: Im not really good with vue-router, how I should do?

Comment: For parameterised routes use this.$router.push({name: 'payouts', params: { pay_id: "SomeID"}});
Or 
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation/SomeID'});

for non parameterised route
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation'});

Answer (score 0):

For parameterised routes use

```
 this.$router.push({name: 'payouts', params: { pay_id: "SomeID"}});
```

Or

```
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation/SomeID'});
```

for non parameterised route

```
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation'});
```